# waitfornottext not present in selenium rc

Tags: testing, automation, selenium-rc

I am testing using Selenium RC but most of the waitforNottext etc are not present in it. Any idea why?

Am I missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use java and Selenium RC then can change condition to negation i.e. -

```
while(count>0)
 if(!selenium.isTextPresent("text")) {
  Thread.Sleep(1000)[
 }
 count--;
}
```

Comment: yeah in this way you can add but I think these already methods are only available in Selenium IDE and not in Selenium rc

Comment: Code snippet mentioned above is for RC and not IDE.